# identify sender of controlTextDidEndEditing

Tags: macos, cocoa

I have a view with three NSTextFields connected to a View Controller that acts as delegate for all three of them.

I have successfully implemented the controlTextDidEndEditing to intercept the text entered by the user and change a property in my model. The method though is unique in the delegate and all the three textfields trigger it. The question is, how can I identify which one of them fired the notification? I can get the NSTextView from the key "NSFieldEditor" of the notification but that doesn't really tell me which one it is. At the beginning I thought of using the NSTextField placeholder but the the method returns me a NSTextView which doesn't seem to have a placeholder property.

Any idea?

Answer (score 8):

You should be able to obtain the reference to the NSTextField via `[notification object]`. If all three of your NSTextFields are available as delegates, it is easy to check which one triggered the event.
Like this:

```
- (void)controlTextDidEndEditing:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    NSTextField* textField = (NSTextField *)[aNotification object];
    if (textField == textField1) {
       // textField1 triggered the event
    } else if (textField == textField2) {
       ...
    } else if (textField == textField3) {
       ...
    }
}
```

Comment: I have the same question but I am working in Swift 5...  I am just starting in Swift and  have trouble to translate the answer....

Comment: This is my code: 
func controlTextDidEndEditing(_ obj: Notification) {
        
        let textField = obj.object as! NSTextField
        print(textField.stringValue)
        
       // if ...  sender ??
        
      }